# How do I determine why a new class isn't running

Tags: fluent-migrator

Background:  VS 2012

We've split out table migrations into separate classes, so we have

class 1,

```
[Migration(1306122)]
class M1306122CreateTableX: Migration
{...}
```

class 2,

```
[Migration(1306123)]
class M1306123CreateTableY: Migration
{...}
```

etc.
Twice I've created a new class, incrementing the migration number, with (what appears to be fully valid code) the migrate process just doesn't run the new class.  There's no error or anything.  It just doesn't run.

Right now we're using a batch file to run the migrate.

```
migrate.exe ^
 /connection "Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Database=%2_Aggregated; Integrated Security=True" ^
 /db SqlServer2012 ^
 /target %1 ^
 /namespace DatabaseMigrations.Aggregated ^
 /nested
```

Is there some way to debug to find out why the new class isn't being included?

Answer (score 3):

Your migrations need to be public classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is nearly always to do with a migration with an incorrect migration id (number). Only migrations that have a larger number than the last run migration will be executed.

For example, if I have executed a migration with id (number) 3 previously and then write a new migration with id 2, when I try to execute my new migration it will be skipped as only migrations with and an id larger than 3 are considered.

You can check this by looking in the VersionInfo table in your database, if the largest number in the Version column is larger than 1306122 or 1306123 then you have found the problem.

Comment: Hmmm.  I've compared the version values and the new classes are definitely larger.  Is there some way to force a version to run, (in the hopes of figuring out why my new classes aren't running).  For example, I've tried doing a migrate:down on a class I know to have run, but it doesn't work.